# Aggregated number from 3 columns in datagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
 private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sum = 0.3;
        double sum1 = 0.4;
        double sum2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            sum = sum * int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            sum = sum * int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            sum1 = sum1 * int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString());
            sum2 = sum1 + sum2;
        }

        textBox8.Text = sum2.ToString();
    }
```

I want to calculate an aggregated mark with 3 mark elements with different weighting percentages. Coursework1 is 30%, coursework 2 is 30% and a final exam being 40%. We also need it to divide it by the amount of objects in the array. Is there anyone that can help me with my code to solve this issue?

Comment: What is a "mark element"?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weight_function In short, multiply the values with their respective weight before adding them up. Also, i have no clue what you are referring to when you speak about "_We also need it to divide it by the amount of objects in the array_"...

Comment: As a start, do make your code readable, name your variables properly.  Have something like `const double CourseworkWeight = 0.3;` and `const int CourseworkColumn=4;`  In your loop, compute the sum of each column (into a variable like `courseworkSum`).  After the loop, divide the sums by the rowcount to get things like `courseworkAverage`.  Once you have the averages, multiply each by the weightings and sum

Comment: @RufusL: in many English-speaking countries, "mark" is a synonym for "grade".  Example: _"What are your marks like this semester?"_

Comment: @Flydog57 Oh, of course! Not sure how I did not get that...

Comment: @RufusL: I'm a Canadian who has lived in the US for 25+ years.  I was here maybe 10 or 15 years before I realized no one knew what I was talking about when I said "mark" or "marks" as synonyms for "grade" or "grades"

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I might create a class to represent a student and give it a property for `Name` as well as for each exam score. Then I would add a property that gives the calculated aggregate score based on the percentages.

Next we can populate a list of these `Student` objects based on the data in your `DataGridView`, and then it's easy to display the aggregates and class average.

For example, the `Student` class might look like:

```
public class Student
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Course1Score { get; set; }
    public int Course2Score { get; set; }
    public int FinalExamScore { get; set; }
    public double AggregateScore => Course1Score * .3 + Course2Score * .3 +
                                    FinalExamScore * .4;
}
```

And then we can populate a list of them and output our results:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var students = new List<Student>();

    for (int i = 0; i <= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        students.Add(new Student
        {
            Name = $"student{i + 1}",
            Course1Score = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString()),
            Course2Score = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString()),
            FinalExamScore = int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value.ToString()),
        });
    }

    string results = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
        students.Select(s => $"{s.Name} had an aggregate score of {s.AggregateScore}"));

    results += "\n\nThe average aggregated score is: " +
                students.Average(student => student.AggregateScore);

    MessageBox.Show(results);
}
```